# Neo4j browser interface stops working or reconnecting

Tags: neo4j

The problem is the same no matter if I am using Safari or Chrome.
After running several times the same query shown below, I am getting the error: Disconnected from Neo4j. Please check if the cord is unplugged.
I am able to SSH to the server and run the query from the shell.
This query was the subject of another issue open earlier and the someone optimize it to the form is presented below. So is not a mater of a not optimized query, seems to be something about the browser interface.
What is wrong here?

```
MATCH (p:Publisher)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)<-[s:AUTHORED]-(a:Author)
MATCH (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w)-[u:INCLUDED]->(b:Bisac) 
WHERE (a.author_name = 'Camus, Albert') 
WITH p,r,w,s,a,l,t,u,b
OPTIONAL MATCH (d:Description)-[v:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(w)
RETURN w, p, a, l, b, d, r, s, t, u, v;
```

More details: when the browser dies in one computer, dies also in the second computer trying to connect to same database.

Also other commands i.e. 
$ rails console 
or 
$ rails s -d 
to start the rails server no longer works.
If I am restarting the Neo4j db server all are working for a little bit and frozen after that.

Below is the execution plan of the query:
neo4j-sh (?)$ EXPLAIN MATCH (p:Publisher)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)<-[s:AUTHORED]-(a:Author{author_name: 'Camus, Albert'}), (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w)-[u:INCLUDED]->(b:Bisac)

> WITH p,r,w,s,a,l,t,u,b
>   OPTIONAL MATCH (d:Description)-[v:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(w)
>   RETURN w, p, a, l, b, d, r, s, t, u, v;
>   +--------------------------------------------+
>   | No data returned, and nothing was changed. |
>   +--------------------------------------------+
>   73 ms

Compiler CYPHER 2.2

Planner COST

OptionalExpand(All)
  |
  +Filter(0)
    |
    +Expand(All)(0)
      |
      +Filter(1)
        |
        +Expand(All)(1)
          |
          +Filter(2)
            |
            +Expand(All)(2)
              |
              +Filter(3)
                |
                +Expand(All)(3)
                  |
                  +NodeUniqueIndexSeek

+---------------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|            Operator | EstimatedRows |                     Identifiers |                       Other |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| OptionalExpand(All) |             5 | a, b, d, l, p, r, s, t, u, v, w | (w)-[v:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(d) |
|           Filter(0) |             5 |       a, b, l, p, r, s, t, u, w |                     b:Bisac |
|      Expand(All)(0) |             5 |       a, b, l, p, r, s, t, u, w |       (w)-[u:INCLUDED]->(b) |
|           Filter(1) |             4 |             a, l, p, r, s, t, w |                  l:Language |
|      Expand(All)(1) |             4 |             a, l, p, r, s, t, w |           (w)<-[t:USED]-(l) |
|           Filter(2) |             4 |                   a, p, r, s, w |                 p:Publisher |
|      Expand(All)(2) |             4 |                   a, p, r, s, w |      (w)<-[r:PUBLISHED]-(p) |
|           Filter(3) |             4 |                         a, s, w |                      w:Woka |
|      Expand(All)(3) |             4 |                         a, s, w |       (a)-[s:AUTHORED]->(w) |
| NodeUniqueIndexSeek |             1 |                               a |        :Author(author_name) |
+---------------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+

Total database accesses: ?
neo4j-sh (?)$

Here is a snapshot from top (before having the browser frozen):
top - 14:59:36 up 46 days, 17:03,  2 users,  load average: 2.66, 4.58, 3.75
Tasks: 116 total,   2 running, 114 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 97.5 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni,  1.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.2 st
KiB Mem:  15666128 total,  3858028 used, 11808100 free,   169612 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  2144784 cached Mem

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
10260 neo4j     20   0 14.348g 1.388g 195316 S 196.9  9.3   1:57.55 java
 9879 ubuntu    20   0   23680   1656   1116 R   0.3  0.0   0:00.88 top
    1 root      20   0   33508   2236    860 S   0.0  0.0   0:12.25 init
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.55 ksoftirqd/0
    4 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:30.10 kworker/0:0
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:39.08 rcu_sched
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 R   0.0  0.0   0:47.50 rcuos/0
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   1:00.72 rcuos/1

Comment: Can you run top on that computer and see if it is busy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser interface of this product Neo4j needs a major overhaul. There is no way to use this interface for serious design, modelling and development.
I executed the following stress tests a from Ruby on Rails console. No errors about disconnect, network etc. All run successfully while any of these queries frozen the browser after 5, 6, 7 executions and even if the result set is limited to 25 records. More than that, I executed all of them while the browser interface was still frozen showing that network disconnect error.

```
(1..1000).each do |n|
  q = "MATCH (p:Publisher)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)<-[s:AUTHORED]-(a:Author)
  WHERE (a.author_name = 'Freud, Sigmund')
  MATCH (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w)-[u:INCLUDED]->(b:Bisac)  
  WITH p,r,w,s,a,l,t,u,b
  OPTIONAL MATCH (d:Description)-[v:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(w)
  RETURN w, p, a, l, b, d, r, s, t, u, v;"

  r = Neo4j::Session.current.query(q)

  print n, "\t", r.count, "\t", Time.now, "\n"
end

(1..1000).each do |n|
  q = "MATCH (p:Publisher)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)<-[s:AUTHORED]-(a:Author)
  WHERE (a.author_name = 'Einstein, Albert')
  MATCH (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w)-[u:INCLUDED]->(b:Bisac)  
  WITH p,r,w,s,a,l,t,u,b
  OPTIONAL MATCH (d:Description)-[v:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(w)
  RETURN w, p, a, l, b, d, r, s, t, u, v;"

  r = Neo4j::Session.current.query(q)

  print n, "\t", r.count, "\t", Time.now, "\n"
end

(1..1000).each do |n|
  q = "MATCH (p:Publisher)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)<-[s:AUTHORED]-(a:Author)
  WHERE (a.author_name = 'Freud, Sigmund')
  MATCH (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w)-[u:INCLUDED]->(b:Bisac)  
  WITH p,r,w,s,a,l,t,u,b
  OPTIONAL MATCH (d:Description)-[v:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(w)
  RETURN w, p, a, l, b, d, r, s, t, u, v;"

  r = Neo4j::Session.current.query(q)

  print n, "\t", r.count, "\t", Time.now, "\n"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the spec of your computer?

How much data does your query return?

```
MATCH (p:Publisher)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)<-[s:AUTHORED]-(a:Author)
WHERE (a.author_name = 'Camus, Albert') 
MATCH (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w)-[u:INCLUDED]->(b:Bisac) 
WITH p,r,w,s,a,l,t,u,b
OPTIONAL MATCH (d:Description)-[v:HAS_DESCRIPTION]-(w)
RETURN w, p, a, l, b, d, r, s, t, u, v;
```

Also what does your visual query plan look like? Please prefix your query with `PROFILE` save as png and share it.

Comment: Too late for top. At this moment the browser interface start working. I did not restarted the server. Nothing is running in that AWS server. It is a dev environment used only by me and hosting only a Neo4j database. Also the query returns 303 records in 0.5 seconds in average. I am able to run all I want from the Neo4j console once I am SSH-ed into the server.

Comment: And the problem with the browser still occurs. It freezes after running the query several times. But I am still running the query successfully in the console. As I said, the problem is not the query but browser interface or maybe is something wrong with the port 7474. Don't know how to fix it.

Comment: From the console: 303 rows, 1601 ms, after all rows are displayed on the screen.

Comment: I edited the query and I provided the execution plan.

Comment: I also edited the issue and added a snapshot from top, before having the browser freezing and giving me the disconnect error.

Comment: While the browser is still frozen, I am able to query the database from the Ruby on Rails console in my laptop. Here are some sample results: evi $ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
irb(main):001:0> a = Author.find_by(author_name: 'Camus, Albert')
=> #<Author author_id: 615454, author_name: "Camus, Albert">
irb(main):002:0> a.wokas.count
=> 223